# Why switchMap(forkJoin) fails but switchMap(arr=>forkJoin(arr)) works fine?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have following code

```
const mySource:Observable<Observable<any>[]>

(...)

mySource.pipe(
   switchMap(arr=>forkJoin(arr));
)
```

which works as expected, but

```
mySource.pipe(
   switchMap(forkJoin);
)
```

fails with

```
REST error TypeError: You provided '0' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    RxJS 31
        subscribeTo
        from
        forkJoinInternal
        _trySubscribe
        subscribe
        innerSubscribe
        _innerSub
```

Why is the second variant not working?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tztgpl?file=index.ts

Keep in mind that this is a runtime error, not an IDE related stuff.

Comment: I believe that is because type signature of `forkJoin` is not assignable to `switchMap` callback type. Maybe because `switchMap` expects second argument which has different type from second argument of `forkJoin`. WHich version of rxjs are  you using?

Comment: Intellij actually likes more variant that does not work, and complaining about forkJoin beeing deprecated in the working option ;) rxjs verion "version": "6.6.3",

Comment: I think the problem is in IDE and not in types. Here https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4deq3j?file=index.ts the same example without type error

Comment: But the error is a runtime error - I totally ignore whatever IDE has to say about it.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tztgpl?file=index.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two calls are actually not equivalent. `switchMap` passes to its projection function two arguments. The value from source and an internal index. You can see it here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/switchMap.ts#L106

So using the following:

```
switchMap(forkJoin),
```

is in fact equivalent to using:

```
switchMap((value, index) => forkJoin(value, index)),
```

... and this obviously throws an error because `0` is not an Observable. Btw, this would stop working in future versions of RxJS anyway because `forkJoin` thinks you're listing source Observales (`forkJoin([obs1, obs2], obs3)`) which is deprecated and it wouldn't subscribe to individual Observables in that array. In other words, it wouldn't flatten the chain.

You can check this small demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-mgb3fx?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Thanks martin for the answer. Did you forgot to fork/save your stackblitz? Whatever is there seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It was my misuse of passed function as it would be Javas method reference.